# TortoiseSVN from the command line and "IF ERRORLEVEL"?

Tags: t-sql, tortoisesvn, batch-file, errorlevel

I have a batch file I'm running from a Windows XP w/service pack 3 workstation which applies SQL changes to a database using sqlcmd.exe in SQL 2005.

I've got a command-line entry for **TortoiseSVN** to automatically update the local copy of my repository like so:

```
tortoiseproc /command:update /path:"C:/SVN/My Code/Dev/2009.07.23" /closeonend:3
```

According to [the documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html), the **/closeonend:3** option will leave the TortoiseSVN dialog box open if any errors, conflicts or merges occur during the update.

If such does occur, and the user closes the dialog without resolving the issues, they could potentially omit changes we want applied to a given branch's test database.

When the TortoiseSVN dialog box is closed in the case of an error, conflict, or merge following an update, will the **ERRORLEVEL** be set to some *nonzero* value, enabling me to bypass the rest of the batch file?  Or will it happily return **0** to indicate it did its job successfully even if the code isn't quite right?

Comment: I would actually just test this. Create a dummy repository locally, C:\Temp\Svn or something, check it out to two directories, add a file to one of them and commit, then update the other, change the file in both, commit in one, and run your batch file in the other to see what happens.

Comment: Why don't you use `svn.exe`? Am I missing something?

Comment: That was my first thought, but I'd rather try to do it all using Tortoise's executable rather than having to maintain both the Tortoise and SVN on an ongoing basis; also who knows if one makes some change at some point that torpedoes the other's functionality in some subtle or painful way.

Comment: Lasse, after testing as you describe it looks like ERRORLEVEL returned is always 0 (this is TortoiseSVN version 1.6.3, Build 16613), so I guess I'll just manually update prior to running the batch and ensure that no errors, conflicts or merges remain unresolved unless someone knows of a way around this. I guess I could maybe build my own wrapper EXE that could look at Tortoise's actual result window dialog and just bail if it finds one of those conditions in the text (using Windows messaging to hook in and intercept the output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just manually updating my local SVN repository prior to performing the other actions in the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I encountered the same thing today and there is a solution...

TortoiseProc returns -1 on error and 0 on success, so the following solved the problem for me:

```
TortoiseProc /path:"%targetdir%" /command:update /closeonend:3
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto SvnError

:SvnSuccess
echo It worked!
goto Done

:SvnError
echo It didn't work!

:Done
```